# Difference of sequences definitely small

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and that $\{b_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence. Suppose that we have already proved that $$a_n-b_n<\varepsilon\quad\text{definitely},$$

can we conclude that $$\sup_na_n-\inf_n b_n<\varepsilon.$$

Intuitively it seems correct, but I don't know how to do it formally.

Comment: Hint: bounded monotonic sequences converge.

Comment: The right-hand side should really be $\leq\varepsilon$ in the second expression.

Comment: @csch2 Thanks, but why?

Comment: In general, when we pass to limits (which is what you do when you take the $\sup$/$\inf$), strict inequalities are loosened to non-strict inequalities. Here is one example where equality (as opposed to $<$) is achieved: let $a_n=1-1/n$ and $b_n=1/n$, which are increasing and decreasing respectively. Then $a_n-b_n = 1-2/n<1$, yet when we pass to the limits we have $\sup a_n-\inf b_n = 1-0 = 1$.

Comment: @Glare Thanks!But how do I formally prove what I asked for in the post above?

Comment: @NatMath Have you followed Thomson's hint yet? Write down the statement of the monotone convergence theorem. Try to apply it to $a_n$ and $b_n$ separately (you will need to show $a_n$ is bounded above and $b_n$ is bounded below somehow). Also, keep in mind that if $s_n<c$ and the $\lim_n s_n$ exists, then $\lim_n s_n\leq c$ as I have illustrated above (you should prove this if you haven't seen the result before--try using contradiction).